# Can not execute hexagon_graph_execution on hexagon-sim

Tags: android, tensorflow, hexagon-dsp

I have followed the [build_and_run_inception_hexagon.sh](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/samples/build_and_run_inception_hexagon.sh) and generated the hexagon_graph_execution executable. Now instead of using a real device I would like to test inception model with `hexagon-sim` available at SDK 3.0. So there is no need to use adb push commands as the SDK can simulate HVX device with hexagon-sim.
I have put the run-time libraries and the inception model plus the image at the same folder. After execution It gives me this error:

```
~/Qualcomm/HEXAGON_Tools/7.2.12/Tools/bin/hexagon-sim ./hexagon_graph_execution "/home/aashouri/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/test/common/inception"
Error: Unsupported machine type 0x0 in ELF image "./hexagon_graph_execution" - exiting.
```

Can anyone comment on this?

`Hexagon-readelf`:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xc8c9c
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          39944896 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         36
  Section header string table index: 35
```

`XXD info`:

```
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0300 2800 0100 0000 9c8c 0c00 3400 0000  ..(.........4...
0000020: c082 6102 0000 0005 3400 2000 0800 2800  ..a.....4. ...(.
0000030: 2400 2300 0600 0000 3400 0000 3400 0000  $.#.....4...4...
0000040: 3400 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0400 0000  4...............
0000050: 0400 0000 0300 0000 3401 0000 3401 0000  ........4...4...
0000060: 3401 0000 1300 0000 1300 0000 0400 0000  4...............
0000070: 0100 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000080: 0000 0000 ece6 2a01 ece6 2a01 0500 0000  ......*...*.....
0000090: 0010 0000 0100 0000 20eb 2a01 20fb 2a01  ........ .*. .*.
```

Comment: Do a `~/Qualcomm/HEXAGON_Tools/7.2.12/Tools/bin/hexagon-readelf -h ./hexagon_graph_execution`.  And maybe a `xxd ./hexagon_graph_execution|head`.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question @Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
```

This binary was not built by hexagon-clang. You must have accidentally built it with the ARM toolchain -- the "Machine" field would say "Qualcomm Hexagon" if it had been built for the hexagon DSP.

Comment: Oh! I see. I thought `hexagon-sim` is able to simulate DSP environment on Android built binary.  So I have to change all those instances of using `GCC` and `clang` in the toolchain with `hexagon-clang` ?

Comment: Yes, at least that.  Building an .so may require more flags, but start with `hexagon-clang`.  BTW there's an SDK 3.2 now that you might prefer.

Comment: Thanks. At first I used that but there are inconsistencies between 3.2 with `Tensorflow HVX` makefiles and runtime that forced me to use 3.0.

Comment: Good point.  Please open another SO question regarding those issues if you don't mind.  Maybe we can sort that out.

Comment: Sure, after this test I will :) Thanks